# Applying session to correct location?

Tags: php, session

I have no idea if I worded that question correctly, but I worded it very carefully. So, basically here's the thing. I have two directories on my local machine.

```
/server/core/
```

and

```
/server/clients/
```

The "core" is what handles all of the data processing, this is done so that if I ever need to update my application then I will just have to update the "core" and all of the "clients" that include and call functions that are located in the "**core**" will be updated automatically. I believe the term for this is a "Dynamic website".

So, basically here's the thing.. I'm using very basic sessions for the time being just to start learning, but I will definately change things around once I'm at a more advanced level. Currently on my "core" i have the following code located in **login.php**

```
if(canLogin) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();};
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Which will load the 'index.php' which is located on the "**client**" directory. Here's how I have this done.

**The following code is located in /server/core/**

```
function createIndex($SQLConnection, $SQLConfig, $PDOConnection) {
    global $action;
    global $days;
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();} 
    if(empty($_SESSION['email'])) 
    {
        createLogin($PDOConnection, $SQLConfig);
    }
}
```

**The following code is located in /server/clients/**

```
<?php
    $Configuration = include_once 'inc/Configuration.php';
    include_once 'inc/Connection.php';
    include_once '/opt/lampp/htdocs/eDashboard2/core/index.php';
    createIndex($NormalConnection, $Configuration, $PDOConnection);
?>
```

Which generates the Index.php file on the core and relays the website back using echos.  Please ignore the multiple SQL Connections as it was for testing and will be removed.

So basically, what the problem is, is that the session isn't being saved, or... rather, **if I had to guess** the session is being stored on **/server/core/** and not on **/server/clients/**

The end-result is that the user is always asked to log in, instead of being able to continue onto the website like they can in the "Client-Only" version of this. (( The client only version was just a static website like you would normally see, the dynamic approach is something I took upon myself to attempt to learn just for the experience ))

**How can I make this so the session will be stored for the person logging in.**

Comment: Is your `core` and `clients` accessible from same domain? E.g. `www.example.com/clients` and `www.example.com/core` or from different domains (like `www.core.com` and `www.clients.com`) ?

Comment: Currently they are on my local machine, my clients are going to be on subdomains such as `client.website.com` while to core i planned to have on either `core.website.com` or just `website.com/core`

Answer (score 1):

Use `session_set_cookie_params` to set the directory to the parent directory:

```
<?php
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params($params['lifetime'], '/server');
```

If the sessions also have to exist between subdomains of your domain, you need an additional parameter:

```
session_set_cookie_params($params['lifetime'], '/server', '.website.com');
```

Comment: If it's for logging in, would I want the parent directory to be the server(core), or the client?

Comment: You have to set it to a directory that contains both scripts, so that a session started in one directory will continue in the other.

Comment: Hmm... so would the approach that I've used up until now not work correctly? Considering I'm having the core(server) echo all of the results to the client? Perhaps I misunderstood what you said. Still my first week messing with php. You made an edit showing the subdomain partition, but.. what if a user logs in on `demo.website.com` using the demo account, and then goes to `example.website.com` would they still be logged in on the other subdomain? or only the one they requested from? Each client has their own database for logging in and polling data.

Comment: Yes, they'll still be logged in. Putting `.website.com` in the cookie means that it applies to all subdomains. Putting a directory in the cookie means it applies to all subdirectories. By default, the session only applies to the subdomain and directory that it was set in.

Comment: So, if I understand what you're saying correctly calling the following line `session_set_cookie_params($params['lifetime'], '/server/client/');` on the **/server/core/** should log the user in once `$_SESSION['email'] = $email;` is called, correct? Considering I use `if(empty($_SESSION['email'])) ` to check to see if the user is "logged in"; However that's not working, would I have to check for the cookie in the sub-domain somehow?

Comment: If you set the directory parameter to `/server/client/` then the session is only visible in that subdirectory, it's not visible in `/server/core/`. You have to set it to a directory that contains **both** scripts for the session to be visible in both subdirectories.

Comment: If the script is in `/server/core`, it can't set the directory to `/server/client`. A script can only set the directory to one of its ancestor directories, it can't be set sideways.

Comment: So would a proper setup for this be something like `/server/core/cleints/` so that the clients and reference from the core? The whole goal of this is to have it setup so everything can be updated to all of the subdomains with a single edit of the "core". That way I don't have to worry about manually updating each client whenever I decided to update the software. From what I'm understanding you're stating that a login system like this is impossible. Could you provide an example of a login system that would only give users access to a certain sub-domain?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54704/discussion-between-christian-tucker-and-barmar).

Comment: Sorry, need to get to sleep.

Comment: You can't give access just to certain subdomains. It's a hierarchical system. Web pages in a certain subdomain or subdirectory can make their cookies and sessions visible to ancestor domains and directories, and then they're visible to all descendants of them.

Comment: Alright! I understand now! My problem is that my "core" and "clients" are currently in totally separate hierarchies. This obviously won't be the case when it's uploaded to a host though. I'll change my file structure around and see what I can do, Thanks!

Comment: What it would amount to is having a user login, and then check that users permissions to see if they are aloud to access said sub-domain, correct? If not simply redirect them.